# Hide datepicker after selecting month

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

Using Datepicker for Bootstrap I want to Limit the view mode to months which is working fine but I want to hide dropdown when I select month.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/datepicker.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


$(function(){
    $('#dp3').datepicker()
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-append date input-group" id="dp3"  data-date="102/2012" data-date-format="mm/yyyy" data-date-viewmode="years" data-date-minviewmode="months">
    <input class="span2 form-control" size="16" type="text" value="02/2012">
    <span class="add-on input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

here is the http://jsfiddle.net/ded3v/6/

Comment: could you fix your jsfiddle to let us play with

Comment: Thanks for response @Wolff , actually I just checked fiddle and don't know why it's not working on chrome but working fine on firefox, please try once on firefox.

Comment: this doesn't work on FF too. You have wrong path for external js scripts, check your console

Comment: Click on time icon, its working fine for me.

Comment: check your network tab, is file http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js cached? This file give me 404 error

Comment: please check the updated fiddle link, I have added js and css inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the datepicker Js to your local server and replace the click function by this one :

```
click: function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = $(e.target).closest('span, td, th');
            if (target.length === 1) {
                switch(target[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
                    case 'th':
                        switch(target[0].className) {
                            case 'switch':
                                this.showMode(1);
                                break;
                            case 'prev':
                            case 'next':
                                this.viewDate['set'+DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].navFnc].call(
                                    this.viewDate,
                                    this.viewDate['get'+DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].navFnc].call(this.viewDate) + 
                                    DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].navStep * (target[0].className === 'prev' ? -1 : 1)
                                );
                                this.fill();
                                this.set();
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case 'span':
                        if (target.is('.month')) {
                            var month = target.parent().find('span').index(target);
                            this.viewDate.setMonth(month);
                            this.element.trigger({type: 'monthSelected', month: month});
                        } else {
                            var year = parseInt(target.text(), 10)||0;
                            this.viewDate.setFullYear(year);
                        }
                        if (this.viewMode !== 0) {
                            this.date = new Date(this.viewDate);
                            this.element.trigger({
                                type: 'changeDate',
                                date: this.date,
                                viewMode: DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].clsName
                            });
                        }
                        this.showMode(-1);
                        this.fill();
                        this.set();
                        break;
                    case 'td':
                        if (target.is('.day') && !target.is('.disabled')){
                            var day = parseInt(target.text(), 10)||1;
                            var month = this.viewDate.getMonth();
                            if (target.is('.old')) {
                                month -= 1;
                            } else if (target.is('.new')) {
                                month += 1;
                            }
                            var year = this.viewDate.getFullYear();
                            this.date = new Date(year, month, day,0,0,0,0);
                            this.viewDate = new Date(year, month, Math.min(28, day),0,0,0,0);
                            this.fill();
                            this.set();
                            this.element.trigger({
                                type: 'changeDate',
                                date: this.date,
                                viewMode: DPGlobal.modes[this.viewMode].clsName
                            });
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        },
```

I just added an "monthSelected" event, so you just have to edit your Js in order to attach an handler to this event :

```
$(function(){
    $('#dp3').datepicker().on('monthSelected', function(ev){
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
        alert("Month number : "+ev.month);
    });
});
```

Comment: Man, it's ok I guess he will see on times it's not like a big company etc :)

Comment: i hope you right... Concerning your "monthSelected" custom event, you could already used the native changeDate event: `$('#dp3').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
        if(ev.viewMode === "months")
            $(this).datepicker('hide');
    });` But still, for UI experience, i think better is to use a delegated dblclick event

Comment: You're right but I think creating an dedicated event is more user-friendly and with that way you can't have the month number easily

Answer (score 2):

You could capture click event:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('.month')) $(e.target).closest('.datepicker.dropdown-menu').hide();
}, true);
```

[DEMO capture](http://jsfiddle.net/ded3v/8/)

Plugin stopping click propagation on .month element, you cannot delegate click event, you can still use following code(delegate dblclick event) to be able to close datepicker on dblclick (i'd suggest you to use this method for better UI experience!):

```
$(document).on('dblclick','.month',function(){
    $(this).closest('.datepicker.dropdown-menu').hide();
});
```

[DEMO dblclick](http://jsfiddle.net/ded3v/9/)